# Why we take the term with cosine of $(α-β)/2$ in amplitude modulation term rather than $(α+β)/2$?

Tags: waves, interference, superposition

In case of beats 
Why do we take cos$\frac{α-β}{2}$ component in modulation of amplitude and not the cos$\frac{α+β}{2}$ term?

[image: this is the image I am referring to]

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the angular velocity $\tfrac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}$ is larger than $\tfrac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2}$ so it is convenient to understand the oscillation as a (fast) oscillation with a (slowly) varying amplitude.

Comment: What if I had swapped both ? What difference would have been made ?

Comment: Well, then you would have a slow oscillation with a very quickly varying amplitude (such that the amplitude possibly changing back and forth several times during one oscillation).

Comment: so all this for reduction of complexity ?

Comment: Well, you could put it this way. I would recommend you to plot a graph of an example oscillation and see which way of thinking seems more natural to you.

Comment: that's too tough for me.I am a beginner.

Comment: Have a look at this plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos((10%2B11)t)cos((10-11)t)

Comment: ohh so I should conclude that both are okay to be taken as  the amplitude modulating frequency but as graph of cos11t is more  complex than cos t we don't use cos 11t as modulating frequency. ??

Comment: Well, to me it looks like a high frequency oscillation whose amplitude slowly varies. :) Maybe play around with this applet as well: https://www.edumedia-sciences.com/en/media/311-amplitude-modulation-am

Comment: Okay thanks for your time and now let's sum up this conversation.What would be the exact cause you will give to why used α-β ? Final words please.

Comment: There is no mathematical reason, one should look at the plot and see why it makes sense to choose this way of thinking intuitively...

Comment: Okay to reduce complexity !!

Comment: You could put it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need only need to look at the graph to see which of the two functions "controls" the amplitude of the other function.

[image]

The graph is the result of the combination of "frequencies" $49$ and $51$.

Note that in one period of the lower frequency component the amplitude of the higher frequency component reaches a maximum twice and so the beat frequency is $\frac {51-49}{2} = 1$.

Comment: One question sir ! If we plot the graph of resultant what determines what ? I mean what does cos α-β/2detremine in the graph and what α+β/2 determine in the graph ?

Comment: It is normally said that you have a high frequency component whose amplitude is modulated by the low frequency component.

Comment: So can I swap both ?

Comment: How would you word the swap?

Comment: using alpha + beta in amplitude and alpha - beta term in rest of it